# Setting datagrid cell template on runtime

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatemplate, datagridcell

I've written a DataTemplate:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ellipseTemplate">
            <Grid Margin="4">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                        
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="Black"  Fill="Gold"/>

            </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
```

And I want to set it to a DateGridCell.Template property in run time.
I can access the cell and change its properties.
I'm using MVVM so I don't want to access it from code-behind
Can I access this template from view model code and set it to the cell Template property?
Or maybe I can build it in the viewmodel in code instead of XAML?

Comment: why would you like to do it in the VM, it should be done in the view
use dataTemplateSelector

Comment: We don't handle UI objects in the view model. Why can't you just set it in XAML?

Comment: I can set it in XAML, but I need to change it in run time, I currently have a converter that changes the cells background and it works fine, but I want to change the template instead of background as I need a shape in the cell and not just a brush color

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be looking for is called CellTemplateSelector.

Take a look at this example:

This shall be placed inside Window.Resources.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Value="Andre">
            <Setter Property="DataGrid.Foreground" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>

    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Path="Name"/>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

</DataTemplate>
```

And this shall be placed inside the DataGridTemplateColumn definition. Any DataGridColumn allows setting CellTemplateSelector.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
    <local:TemplateSelector 
     DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"                          
    </local:TemplateSelector>
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
```

In the example I gave you the guy had a custom TemplateSelector which he defined inside CellTemplateSelector like this: `<local:TemplateSelector...`

To read more about CellTemplateSelector or generally about ContentTemplateSelectors I suggest you to check following links out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The last link one has an MSDN example which you should check out too.